# select stmt->fetch doesn't show the queries after a variable LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, fetch

So I have more queries which contain the values taken from `$keywords` which doesnt appear when i called the `stmt->fetch()` my tables have the some structure(colums) so I tried to search into keywords(column) and then show the queries which titlu(column) contain the specifically keywords(`$keywords`) but does not show me nothing even if an exemple I have in the keywords column  value **top** others queries which has in the column keywords value **top**

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT keywords FROM stiinta WHERE link = ? LIMIT 1');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $pageid);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($keyword);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
while ($stmt->fetch())    {
   $keyword;    // faci acelasi lucru fara $row 
}
$stmt->close();
```

test

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM stiinta WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  ? UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM travel WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  ? UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM stiinta WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  ? UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM natura WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  ? UNION SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews FROM lifestyle WHERE   approved='1' AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  ? LIMIT 10");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $keyword, $keyword, $keyword, $keyword, $keyword);
$stmt->execute();
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "a aparut o eroare";}
$stmt->bind_result($id, $titluKEY, $linkKEY, $pozaKEY, $altKEY, $keywordKEY, $linknewsKEY);//variabla pe care o vrei inlocuita prin bind_Result in loc de get_Result
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {// verificare daca este vrun query
    echo "You did not have any queries to match.<br>";
} else {
$stiintalist = '';
while ($stmt->fetch())    {
    $id;
    $titluKEY;
    $linkKEY;
    $pozaKEY;
    $altKEY; 
    $keywordKEY;
    $linknewsKEY;   // faci acelasi lucru fara $row trb sa fie in concordanta cu ceea ce este in SELECT column pentretu teste a href="/page-stiinta.php?pid='.$linkKEY.'"
    $stiintalist .= '<div id="articol-content-more"><a href="/'.$linknewsKEY.'"><img src="/images/'.$pozaKEY.'.jpg"class="articol-content-more-image" alt="'.$altKEY.'"><p class="articol-content-more-title">'.$titluKEY.'</p></a><span><a class="articol-content-more-afla" href="/'.$linknewsKEY.'">Citește mai multe</a></span><span class="articol-content-more-fl"><div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="button_count" data-href="http://esticurios.ro/'.$linknewsKEY.'"></div></span></div>';        
    }
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

echo $stiintalist;
```

is show me *You did not have any queries to match* so that means `$stmt->num_rows == 0` is null, even if I have the some words in the others queries....

Answer (score 0):

Could be you column is type char  then try adding wildchar

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("

    SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews 
    FROM stiinta 
    WHERE   approved='1' 
      AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%') 
    UNION 
    SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews 
    FROM travel 
    WHERE   approved='1' 
      AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%') 
    UNION 
    SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews 
    FROM stiinta 
    WHERE   approved='1' 
      AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%') 
    UNION 
    SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews 
    FROM natura 
    WHERE   approved='1' 
      AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%') 
    UNION 
    SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews 
    FROM lifestyle 
    WHERE   approved='1' 
      AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%') 
    LIMIT 10
    ");
```

Comment: Didnot show me any results..  is giveing me the echo condition of  `$stmt->num_rows == 0` so means somethings i Missed

Comment: Try with only a select with SQL ide and be sure your query is correct .. eventually show a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: i try with only `SELECT id, titlu, link, poza, alt, keywords, linknews 
    FROM stiinta 
    WHERE   approved='1' 
      AND  replace(replace(replace(titlu, ',', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '') LIKE  concat('%', ? , '%')` but same problem...

Comment: sorry for the double post I called `$num_of_rows = $stmt->num_rows;` after the `$stmt->store_result();` and give me value `0` so something i missed on the select statement...

Comment: Using the query in your comment in a sql console or IDE  ..the query work right or not  ?

Comment: the problems is the `$keyword` because contain more words and special characters like # , black space and the words stars with #  e.g. of value (#top, #travel, #hashtags) because doesnt give me any queries... ``if i change with  $test = "top";
$stmt->bind_param("s", $test);`` is work...(show the queries which containt the column titlu the word from ``$test``) but if i change the ``$test = "#top"` is give me 0 query...

Answer (score 0):

Since your `$pageid` is probably an integer (?), you could try to change the second line to

```
$stmt->bind_param('i', $pageid);
```